# cannot query field "allMdx" on type "Query"

Tags: reactjs, graphql, gatsby

I'm new in GraphiQl, I'm flowing tutorials from [here](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-source-filesystem)

And also I'm new to Gatsby, after all requirement plugin install (guide from gatsby offical doc) when I want to go on this link: `http://localhost:8000/___graphql` then show me an error on `allMdx` if I hover on it.

like this: [image]

but official document everything is ok, I don't know where is my problem.

any update issue!

I have used `gatsby v3`

also my initial query not match with [this](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/tutorial/part-4/)

Any suggestion please.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically, the GraphQL playground (`localhost:8000/___graphql`) is telling you that you have no `allMdx` node created. The list of all available nodes are in the left column (`allFile`, `allDirectory`, etc).

You need to set the filesystem to allow Gatsby to inferr that nodes by:

```
npm install gatsby-source-filesystem
```

Then, in your `gatsby-config.js`:

```
module.exports = {
  siteMetadata: {
    title: "My First Gatsby Site",
  },
  plugins: [
    "gatsby-plugin-gatsby-cloud",
    "gatsby-plugin-image",
    "gatsby-plugin-sharp",
    {
      resolve: "gatsby-source-filesystem",
      options: {
        name: `blog`,
        path: `${__dirname}/blog`, // <-- the folder where you have the .mdx files
      }
    },
  ],
};
```

If you have some MDX files in `/blog` folder, Gatsby will generate the proper nodes (`allMdx`), allowing you to query them.

Restart and clean your server by `gatsby clean && gatsby develop`.

The next steps are related to query the data by adding some configuration such as:

```
{
  resolve: `gatsby-plugin-mdx`,
  options: {
    defaultLayouts: {
      posts: require.resolve("./src/components/blog-layout.js"),
      default: require.resolve("./src/components/layout.js"),
    },
  },
},
```

*Note: you'll need to install the [`gatsby-plugin-mdx`](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-plugin-mdx/) plugin first*

You can check the following tutorial: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/gatsbyjs-mdx-in-gatsby

Remember to clean cache (`gatsby clean`) in each trial and to stop and re-run de develop.

Comment: Thanks I have forgotten to restart the server..:D

Comment: I did everything above, but not the `gatsby clean`. Only restarting the server did not work. But after doing `gatsby clean` first then `gatsby develop` it works. They should totally add this on their docs.